# How to mock method that belongs to inner object

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs

Is it possible to mock a method which belongs to object that I have in my class UnderTest.

`Update` method is executed when event from child component is emitted. I wanted to mock `service.saveNewElement(data)` which allows me test data in `then()` block

```js
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Service } from 'secret';
import ROUTES from '../../../../router/routes.const';


@Component({
    name: 'UnderTest',
    template: require('./underTest.component.html'),
})
export default class UnderTest extends Vue {
    private service: Service;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.service = new Service();
    }

    public update(data: any): void {
        this.service
            .saveNewElement(data)
            .then(() => {
                //stuff to do
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.$notify.error('Oops!, sth went wrong...');
            });
    }

}
</script>
```

Does anyone know a way to do this?

EDIT:

Tip from @slideshowp2 works but i have another problem.

I have used that

```js
jest.mock('../../services/customer.service',() => ({
    constructor: jest.fn(() => {}),
    saveNewCustomer: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: 3 }))
}));
```

in my test file. Then i have an error like `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: service.Service is not a constructor"`

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: It's very difficult when you `new` up the service in the constructor - look up "dependency inversion".

Comment: Jonrsharpe, I'm aware of that. But in order to do that, I have to rebuild the application. I use Jest.js and vue-test-utils for testing. Do you see any other solutions? If not, I will try to do what you suggested.

Comment: Jonsharpe, do You know why that error could occur? `Injection "service" not found`. I did every step from article [link](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/the-ioc-container-pattern-with-vue).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually mock the `Service` imported using `jest.mock(moduleName)` and put your mocked `Service` into `__mocks__` directory, I make a sample for your question.

The file structure is:

```sh
.
├── __mocks__
│   └── someService.ts
├── index.spec.ts
├── index.ts
└── someService.ts
```

`someService.ts`:

```js
class SomeService {
  public async saveNewElement(data) {
    return 'real data';
  }
}

export { SomeService };
```

`index.ts`:

```js
import { SomeService } from './someService';

export default class UnderTest {
  private service: SomeService;

  constructor() {
    this.service = new SomeService();
  }

  public update(data: any): any {
    return this.service.saveNewElement(data).then(res => {
      // stuff to do
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

`__mocks__/someService.ts`:

```js
const mockedSomeService = {
  saveNewElement: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('mocked data')
};
const SomeService = jest.fn(() => mockedSomeService);

export { SomeService, mockedSomeService };
```

The unit test:

```js
import UnderTest from './';

jest.mock('./someService.ts');

const underTest = new UnderTest();

describe('UnderTest', () => {
  it('t1', async () => {
    console.log = jest.fn();
    await underTest.update('jest');
    expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('mocked data');
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57775960/index.spec.ts
  UnderTest
    ✓ t1 (14ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.911s, estimated 2s
```

=================UPDATE================

You can mock the imported module using `jest.mock(path, moduleFactory)` without `__mocks__` directory as well.

```js
import UnderTest from './';

const mockedSomeService = {
  saveNewElement: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('mocked data')
};

jest.mock('./someService.ts', () => {
  return {
    SomeService: jest.fn(() => mockedSomeService)
  };
});

const underTest = new UnderTest();

describe('UnderTest', () => {
  it('t1', async () => {
    console.log = jest.fn();
    await underTest.update('jest');
    expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith('mocked data');
  });
});
```

P.S. It's easy to test when you are using DIP so that you can mock and inject the dependencies easier than the way that import dependencies. You'd better import(depend on) the abstract(interface/abstract class), not the concrete class(the `SomeService`)

Comment: slideshowp2 could u watch my EDIT section in post? Thank You.

Comment: I have constructor in my Service class when u run test with code You propsed I am getting an error `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: _customer.CustomerService is not a constructor"`. Could I mock entire class via `jest.mock` or should I use Dependency Inversion Pattern?

Comment: @akaras Both of these two ways are ok. Please check demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57775960